# Qt fetched database record field values are empty, the data EXISTS in database

Tags: mysql, qt

I have Qt/QML app that connects to database and now I would like to fetch data through sublcassed `QSqlQueryModel`:

```
#ifndef UEPEOPLEMODEL_H
#define UEPEOPLEMODEL_H

#include <QImage>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QHash>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlQuery>

#include "../settings/uedefaults.h"
#include "../settings/uetypes.h"

class UePeopleModel : public QSqlQueryModel,
                      public QQuickImageProvider
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QSqlDatabase m_ueDb;

private:
    QSqlDatabase ueDatabase() const
        { return this->m_ueDb; }
    void ueSetDatabase(const QSqlDatabase& database)
        { this->m_ueDb=database; }

public:
    UePeopleModel(QObject *parent=0);
    ~UePeopleModel();

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index,
                  int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QImage ueImage(const QString &id) const;
    QImage requestImage(const QString &id,
                        QSize *size,
                        const QSize &requestedSize);
    UeTypeRoles roleNames() const;

public:
    static const int ueRoleName=Qt::UserRole+1;
    static const int ueRoleImage=Qt::UserRole+2;
};

#endif // UEPEOPLEMODEL_H
```

and here is implementation:

```
#include "uepeoplemodel.h"

UePeopleModel::UePeopleModel(QObject* parent)
    : QSqlQueryModel(parent),
      QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,
                          QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading)
{
    //QSqlDatabase db;

    if(!QSqlDatabase::connectionNames().contains(UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionNames::DATABASE_CONNECTION_NAME_PEOPLE,
                                                 Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        this->ueSetDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(UePosDatabase::DATABASE_DRIVER,
                                                      UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionNames::DATABASE_CONNECTION_NAME_PEOPLE));
    }   // if

    this->ueDatabase().setHostName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbHostname()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_HOSTNAME);
    this->ueDatabase().setDatabaseName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbName()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_NAME);
    this->ueDatabase().setUserName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbUser()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_USERNAME);
    this->ueDatabase().setPassword(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbPassword()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    if(this->ueDatabase().open())
    {
        this->setQuery(UePosDatabase::UeSqlQueries::UeTablePeople::SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PEOPLE,
                       this->ueDatabase());
        //qDebug() << this->ueDatabase().lastError().text();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << this->ueDatabase().lastError().text();
    }
}   // default constructor

UePeopleModel::~UePeopleModel()
{
}   // default destructor

QVariant UePeopleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
                             int role) const
{
    QVariant value=QVariant();

    switch(role)
    {
        case ueRoleImage:
        {
            value=this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_IMAGE).toByteArray();

            break;
        }   // case

        case ueRoleName:
        {
            value=this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_NAME).toString();

            break;
        }   // case

        default:
            return value;
    }   // switch

    return QSqlQueryModel::data(index,
                                role);//value;
}   // data

QImage UePeopleModel::ueImage(const QString &id) const
{
    return QImage::fromData(this->record(id.toInt()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_IMAGE).toByteArray(),
                            "PNG");
}   // image

QImage UePeopleModel::requestImage(const QString &id,
                                   QSize *size,
                                   const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    Q_UNUSED(requestedSize);

    QImage image=this->ueImage(id);

    *size = image.size();

    return image;
}   // requestImage

UeTypeRoles UePeopleModel::roleNames() const
{
    UeTypeRoles roles;
    const int iRoleName=UePeopleModel::ueRoleName;
    const int iRoleImage=UePeopleModel::ueRoleImage;

    roles.insert(iRoleName,
                 "ueRoleName");
    roles.insert(iRoleImage,
                 "ueRoleImage");

    return roles;
}   // roleNames
```

Now, the problem is I get emtpty values from database, and therefore qml outputs errors:

```
> qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:140:43: Unable to assign [undefined] to
> QString qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:140:43: Unable to assign
> [undefined] to QString qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:118:33: QML
> Image: Failed to get image from provider:
> image://uepeoplemodel/undefined qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:118:33:
> QML Image: Failed to get image from provider:
> image://uepeoplemodel/undefined qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:140:43:
> Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
> qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:140:43: Unable to assign [undefined] to
> QString qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:140:43: Unable to assign
> [undefined] to QString qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:140:43: Unable to
> assign [undefined] to QString qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:118:33:
> QML Image: Failed to get image from provider:
> image://uepeoplemodel/undefined qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:118:33:
> QML Image: Failed to get image from provider:
> image://uepeoplemodel/undefined qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:118:33:
> QML Image: Failed to get image from provider:
> image://uepeoplemodel/undefined qrc:/gui/windows/UeKeypad.qml:118:33:
> QML Image: Failed to get image from provider:
> image://uepeoplemodel/undefined
```

Why am I getting empty values from table?!
Hmm, I've been doing research on problem, and in Qt docs it states:

> If the model is not initialized, an empty record will be returned.

The link to docs: [QSqlQueryModel::record](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#record/). This might be the problem, however, I initialize UePeopleModel in `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    UePeopleModel* uePeopleModel=new UePeopleModel(qApp);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePeopleModel",
                                             uePeopleModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

What am I still missing? I've checked db connection numerous times, it is ok, I also get field names from table, but no data.

Hmm, I've added debug code to `QVariant UePeopleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role)` const method:

```
QVariant UePeopleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
                             int role) const
{
    switch(role)
    {
        case ueRoleImage:
        {
            return this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_IMAGE).toByteArray();

            break;
        }   // case

        case ueRoleName:
        {
            int nrrecords=this->rowCount(QModelIndex());
            QString name=this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_NAME).toString();;

            return this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_NAME).toString();
        } break; // case

        case ueRolePassword:
        {
            QString password=this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_APPPASSWORD).toString();

            return this->record(index.row()).value(UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_APPPASSWORD).toString();
        } break;   // case

        default:
            return QVariant();
    }   // switch

    return QSqlQueryModel::data(index,
                                role);//value;
}   // data
```

and after the line `int nrrecords=this->rowCount(QModelIndex());` I've set a breakpoint, the temp variable `nrrecord` holds value 5 - which is excatly number of records in database! Why is then method's parameter `index` empty?? The `data()` method is being called from QML file via QML items `model` property.

Comment: Show us the SQL that is executed, but fails to provide the desired results.

Comment: @RickJames SQL statement is:`SELECT ID, NAME, APPPASSWORD, CARD, ROLE, VISIBLE, IMAGE FROM PEOPLE WHERE VISIBLE=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are following problems at least:

1. Your switch cases all fall through (you must `break` after each one).
2. You don't need any accessors to the private members, you are supposed to use them directly. That's why they are private. Accessors are used as encapsulation when you want to *isolate* the implementation details from *public* (or *protected*) interface. Remove the accessors for `m_ueDb` and use the member directly.
3. Your implementation of `data` will only provide values for image roles. You must forward the default role access to the base class's `data()`:

   ```
   QVariant UePeopleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
   {
     switch(role) {
     case ueRoleImage:
       for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<this->record().count(); iIndex++) {
         qDebug() << this->record().fieldName(iIndex) << 
                  << this->record().value(iIndex) << 
                  << index.row();
       }
       return record(index.row()).value(
         UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_IMAGE).toByteArray();

     case ueRoleName:
       return record(index.row()).value(
         UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_NAME).toString();
     }
     return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
   }
   ```
4. You should never use the `<QtModule/QtHeader>` include style. That you do indicates that your `.pro` file doesn't declare the use of the `sql` module and/or that you haven't re-run *qmake* on your project after adding the module to the project (you should have `QT += sql` somewhere in your `.pro` file). Fix as follows:

   ```
   // CORRECT
   #include <QSqlError>
   // WRONG
   #include <QtSql/QSqlError>
   ```

Comment: @KubaOder, here are my notices:
Answer 1) Ok, will access member directly, but I did connect to database, I was overwatching both side (app and mysql server, the connection was alive, in my question I even got filed names at runtime, that would not be possible without succesfull db connection)
Answer 2) I am aware of that, but I am trying to follow the rule every member has getter/setter.
Anwser 3) How do I forward default role to base class's data()?
Answer 4) I do not see the relation between include file and .pro file. I have QT += sql in my .pro file. I think you are wrong.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih You simply don't need `QtSql/` prefix in the include paths. It is not, and has never been necessary in recent times. If you use it, you're hiding project configuration errors and merely relegating problems to the link time. The relation between include paths and `.pro` is simple: if you miss `QT += sql` from the `.pro` file, the `<QSqlError>` include will fail, but `<QtSql/QSqlError>` will "work" - it will compile, but won't link.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih "I am trying to follow the rule every member has getter/setter" That rule has a *reason*, and the reason is encapsulation from the *users* of your class. When you implement the class, you're not the user, you're you. There's zero reason for encapsulation then - so don't do it. These rules must make sense to you, otherwise you're wasting time on voodoo cult.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih I was wrong about point 1, so I removed it. `QSqlDatabase` is a explicitly shared class, not really a plain value class.

Comment: ok, but still, why do I get field names and not data istself??

Comment: @KubaOder it did not work because I had `case` statements in wrong places and at `default` now I have `return QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);`.